# Forbidden access (Flooding) in Joomla with SH404SEF extension on Localhost

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to make an instance of my live fully functional Joomla 1.5 website on my localhost (MAMP).

I created a new database and imported the live database, copied the Joomla files and updated the config.php file.

Can access the Joomla administration back-end interface but unable to access the front end.

I get Forbidden access (Flooding) error, I tried disabling the SH404 plugins but that did not help me.

I increased the SH404 flooding limit and even that did not help me.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file : `administrator/components/com_sh404sef/custom.sef.php`

Edit this variable:`shDefaultParams['sh404SEF_USE_NON_STANDARD_PORT']=0`

To `shDefaultParams['sh404SEF_USE_NON_STANDARD_PORT']=1`